# Find the indefinite integral $\int\frac{dx}{(x^2+2x+5)^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

I need help with the indefinite integral 
\begin{align}
& \int\frac{dx}{(x^2+2x+5)^2} \\[10pt]
= {} & \int\frac{dx}{((x+1)^2+4)^2} = \int\frac{du}{(u^2+4)^2} & & x+1=u,\quad du=dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{1}{16} \int\frac{du}{(\frac{u^2}{4}+1)^2} \\[10pt]
= {} &  \frac 1 8 \int \frac{ds}{(s^2+1)^2} = \text{?} & & \frac u 2 = s, \quad 2\,ds=du
\end{align}

or maybe there is an easier way ?

Any ideas ? thanks !

Comment: try $u = 2 \tan t$

Comment: Can you show me how to do it ?

Comment: Find the primitive of $\frac{ds}{s^2+a}$ and differentiate it with respect to $a$, then set $a=1$.

Answer (score 3):

it is $$x^2+2t+5=(x+1)^2+4$$ we Substitute $$x+1=t$$ then we have $$dx=dt$$
and $$\int\frac{1}{(t^2+4)^2}dt$$ and then we Substitute $$t=2\tan(s)$$ with $$dt=2\sec^2(s)ds$$ and we get $$(t^2+4)^2=16\sec^4(s)$$ and our integral is $$2\int \frac{\cos^2(s)}{16}ds$$ and in the last step note that $$\cos^2(s)=\frac{1}{2}\cos(2s)+\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you write $s = \tan(t)$ then you obtain $\sec^2(t)\,\mathrm{d}t = \mathrm{d} s$ and
$$
 \int \frac{1}{(1+s^2)^2}\,\mathrm{d}{s}=\int \cos^2(t)\,\mathrm{d}{t}
$$
you can then solve the second integral by using the double-angle formula for cosine.

Comment: You have $s=\tan t$ so that $ds = \sec^2 t\,\mathrm{d} t,$ and then $$ \int \frac{1}{1+s^2}\,\mathrm{d}{s}=\int \cos^2(t)\,\mathrm{d}{t}. $$ That is not correct. What you need is $$ \int \frac{1}{(1+s^2)^2}\,\mathrm{d}{s} = \int \cos^2(t)\,\mathrm{d}{t}. $$

Answer (score 1):

There is a reduction process. Apply integration by parts.

$$\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx=\frac{x}{1+x^2}-\int x \,d\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
$$=\frac{x}{1+x^2}+2\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx-2\int \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx$$
And rearranging, 
$$2\int \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx=\frac{x}{1+x^2}+\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx$$